# Creating a pivot table from a master sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

there is a lot of information on pivot tables on the internet. However, I am having trouble myself. I basically want to create a pivot table from one master sheet and create a pivot table by "product group and category" on a new worksheet. The code I created is below,

```
sub createPivotTableExistingSheet()
 
    'declare variables - source data cell range
    Dim myFirstRow As Long
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myFirstColumn As Long
    Dim myLastColumn As Long
 
    'declare variables - source and destination cell range address
    Dim mySourceData As String
    Dim myDestinationRange As String
 
    'declare object variables
    Dim mySourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim myDestinationWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim myPivotTable As PivotTable
    
 Sheets.Add.Name = "Pivot Table"
 
    'source and destination worksheets
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set mySourceWorksheet = .Worksheets("MasterSheet")
        Set myDestinationWorksheet = .Worksheets("Pivot Table")
    End With
 
    'obtain address of destination cell range
    myDestinationRange = myDestinationWorksheet.Range("A5").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
 
    'identify row and column numbers that define source data cell range
    myFirstRow = 5
    myLastRow = 20005
    myFirstColumn = 1
    myLastColumn = 50
 
    'obtain address of source data cell range
    With mySourceWorksheet.Cells
        mySourceData = .Range(.Cells(myFirstRow, myFirstColumn), .Cells(myLastRow, myLastColumn)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    End With
 
    'create Pivot Table cache and create Pivot Table report based on that cache -ERROR MESSAGE "Run time error 5"
    Set myPivotTable = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=mySourceWorksheet.Name & "!" & mySourceData).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=myDestinationWorksheet.Name & "!" & myDestinationRange)
 
 
    'add, organize and format Pivot Table fields
    With myPivotTable
        .PivotFields("Product group and catergory").Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
        With .PivotFields("Product group and catergory ")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 2
            .Function = xlCount
        End With
    End With
 
End Sub
```

the error occurs at the create pivot table cache stage, ive tried debugging it myself but im not quite sure where I am going wrong. If anyone could help that would be great. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivottable creation works best when you separate the pivotcache and table creation into separate lines.

Also - note you can pass a range object to the (eg) `SourceData` parameter instead of the more-awkward `sheetname!address` construct.

For example:

```vb
Sub createPivotTableExistingSheet()
 
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable, pc As PivotCache
    
    'source and destination worksheets
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsSource = .Worksheets("MasterSheet")
        Set wsDest = .Worksheets.Add()
    End With
    wsDest.Name = "Pivot Table"
    
    With wsSource
        Set rngSource = .Range("A5").CurrentRegion '(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(20005, 50))
    End With
    
    Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                             SourceData:=rngSource)
    
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=wsDest.Range("A5"))
    
    With pt
        .PivotFields("Product group and category").Orientation = xlRowField
        '.Position = 1
        With .PivotFields("DataField")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            '.Position = 2
            .Function = xlCount
        End With
    End With
 
End Sub
```